# Is there a way to determine if the data is updated

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So say I have a csv file with data and upload it on sql developer and then I make changes to the csv file and then upload it again on the sql developer which does gives me error.

Is there any way to upload the changed data in the csv file on the sql developer and it will notify saying these rows are updated?

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean, "upload it on sql developer "  sql developer is not a database.

Comment: orcale sql developer